# <MailDefinition> and <%%> placeholders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

...

*BodyFileName* attribute references disk file containing mail's body text. If we put placeholders `<% UserName %>` and `<% Password %>`in the body text file ( *RegistrationMail.txt* ), then *CreateUserWizard* will automatically replace these placeholders with username and password of a created user.

A) If I wanted to create a control that would also be able to replace placeholders `<% %>` in a file with some text, how would I do that?

B) Can I also write into these placeholders from code behind file? Meaning, is there some method which when called, writes specific text into placeholder contained inside some txt file?

thanx

Answer (score 9):

A simple string.Replace() called in the SendingMail event does the trick.

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail( object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e )
{
    // Replace <%foo%> placeholder with foo value
    e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace( "<%foo%>", foo );
}
```

Creating your own emailing mechanism isn't that difficult either.

```
using( MailMessage message = new MailMessage() )
{
    message.To.Add( "none@none.com" );
    message.Subject = "Here's your new password";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = GetEmailTemplate();

    // Replace placeholders in template.
    message.Body = message.Body.Replace( "<%Password%>", newPassword );
    message.Body = message.Body.Replace( "<%LoginUrl%>", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority ) + FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl ); // Get the login url without hardcoding it.

    new SmtpClient().Send( message );
}

private string GetEmailTemplate()
{
    string templatePath = Server.MapPath( @"C:\template.rtf" );

    using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( templatePath ) )
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```